# How to detect changes in the bound form variable value in a custom form control (Angular 10)

Tags: angular

I've created an Angular custom form component that implements the `ControlValueAccessor` interface so it can be used like this:

```html
<form [formGroup]="formModel">
  <my-custom-control formControlName="config_name"
    label="{{ 'INPUT_CONFIG.LABEL' | translate }}"></my-custom-control>

</form>
```

The component needs to do some logic whenever the `config_name` form variable changes. How could I detect this change inside the custom component (not the parent)?

I've tried implementing the `OnChanges` interface, but the `SimpleChanges` object received doesn't have any reference to the bound form variable.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Can you share your custom control component code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the solution just before my eyes: the `writeValue` method implemented from the `ControlValueAccessor` does exactly what I need but I misunderstood the documentation. Now I can parse whatever value the custom form control gets:

```js
writeValue(newValue: string) {
  if(newValue) {
    this.parseNameValue(newValue); // Do the needed logic to parse the value
  } else {
    this.value = '';
  }
}
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
this.formModel.get("config_name").valueChanges.subscribe(change => {
     // do something 
});
```

Comment: Hi, I just answered about a similar suggestion given by Naeem Bashir :)

Answer (score 0):

this should be posted in ngOnint:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.formModel.get('config_name').valueChanges.subscribe(x => {
        
    console.log(this.form.get("id").value)
          
         
  })
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the suggestion, but I was thinking about detecting the change inside the custom form component, not from the parent. My idea is to use something similar to this: `@Input() set boundProperty (value: boolean) { // Do something when the bound property changes }`.

Comment: i hope this will be helpful. we should support each other.